# Not getting proper response from server using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not getting server response from server using jquery.But when I check from server end server end guy get the response .I am sending same value in parameter ,But not getting the response ?

can you please help me out ?
This image is when server person check .It is getting response.

But

http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/LsKbJ/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //event handler for submit button
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            //collect userName and password entered by users
            var userName = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            //call the authenticate function
            authenticate(userName, password);
        });
    });

    //authenticate function to make ajax call
    function authenticate(userName, password) {
       $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
       url: "http://dd.c-dd.de/cc/REST/Login",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        //json object to sent to the authentication url
        data: {Application:"61136208-742B-44E4-B00D-C32ED26775A3",
        Device:"null",
        LoginKind:"0", Password: "1",Username:"qus"},
        success: function (t) {
        alert(t+"df")
        },
        error:function(data){alert(data+"dfdfd")}
    })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST/Login. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Cross Origin Policy restricts connecting to different domain name

Comment: how to remove that  allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Remote host should sent "Origin" header containing current host of the document that requested

Comment: Chrome says that Origin sends right, but remote host responds with http code 400

Comment: I also change chrome property "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --disable-web-security

Comment: I've submitted data by simple connect, server still says 400

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38414/discussion-between-user2648752-and-rowman-pirce)